# How to stop UIActivityIndicator after UISearchBar has finished in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uiactivityindicatorview

So my set up:

I'm have an app set up with Parse, and I'm using a `PFQueryTableViewController`. I've added a `UISearchBar` to my screen. I have this search all set up and working fine.

**Question:** To make it a bit more obvious to the user that the search is being performed, I want to add a `UIActivityIndicator` so they can see something is loading. I will also `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()` so they cannot use the app until the search is complete.

I'm currently having issues with how to make the `UIActivityIndicator` stop animating, and to `endIgnoringInteractionEvents()`- I just can't work out where I would place this code:

`spinningActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()`

I have placed my code for the `UIActivityIndicator` inside the method `func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)` so that once they click search on the keyboard, the spinner will start.

But where can I place the code to stop it animating and enable the app again?

The code I added for the UISearchBar is as follows:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true

    self.loadObjects()

}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    // Dismiss the keyboard
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    // Force reload of table data
    self.loadObjects()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    // Dismiss the keyboard
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    spinningActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    spinningActivityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    spinningActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    spinningActivityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(spinningActivityIndicator)
    spinningActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents() 

    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false

    // Force reload of table data
    self.loadObjects()

}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    // Clear any search criteria
    searchBar.text = ""

    // Dismiss the keyboard
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    // Force reload of table data
    self.loadObjects()
}
```

and in the `func queryForTable() -> PFQuery` I added:

```
    if filmSearchBar.text != "" {
        query.whereKey("FilmName", containsString: filmSearchBar.text!)

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what is your search actually doing, performing a call to a server or just filtering a local datasource?

Comment: where do you get the results from the search? because this is the place where you stop the activity indicator

Comment: @dzk Yes I believe it is. This was the first time i've worked with a `UISearchBar`. I followed along on this tutorial if this helps: http://blog.bizzi-body.com/2015/03/08/how-to-search-within-a-parse-com-view-table/ - They add the search section about half way down the page.

Comment: It has not much to do with `UISearchBar`, it has to do with your completion of `self.loadObjects()`. If it is a time consuming process, do it upon completion of that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked through some of the documentation for `PFQueryTableViewController`, and there's a method `objectsDidLoad()` that seems promising. So, try adding this below your `queryForTable()` function:

```
override func objectsDidLoad(error: NSError?) {
    super.objectsDidLoad(error)
    // Your code here to stop the UIActivityIndicator
}
```

And you could add a `print("objectsDidLoad")` inside the function to see that it works.